# Change avatar border color in React.JS

Tags: css, reactjs

I have simple project in React.Js, in header I have avatar, when I change avatar `border-color`, there is not any change.

**Header.css:**

```
.header__avatar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-color: #ff000;
  border-width: 2px;
  overflow: "hidden";
}

.header__avatar > h3 {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

**Header.js**:

```
<div class="header__avatar">
    <h3>name</h3>
    <HeaderOption  avatar={true} />
</div>
```

**Expected Avatar:**

[image]

Comment: What is ".red" ?

Comment: I miss color, it is hex code

Comment: And have u solved ur problem already?

Comment: @testing_22 not yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `0` in the border color. It should be `#ff0000` and not `#ff000`.
So it must be:

```
.header__avatar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border-color: #ff0000;
    border-width: 2px;
    overflow: "hidden";
}
```

To have a round avatar with border, you also should add the `border` property and `border-radius` property to see the changes.

Example:

```
.header__avatar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border: thick solid;
  border-color: #ff0000;
  border-width: 2px;
  overflow: "hidden";
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.header__avatar > h3 {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

---

```
<img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="header__avatar">
<h3>SampleName</h3>
</div>
```

**Sample Output:**[image]

You can check this out for yourself at:[TryItYourself-HowToCreateAvatarImages](http://w3schools-fa.ir/howto/tryit7550.html?filename=tryhow_css_image_avatar)

Comment: I have made the necessary changes. Please check :-)

Comment: not, text color change, and rectangular consist text and avatar

Comment: u are not understand question I guess

Comment: Do you want name inside the avatar border or outside?

Comment: I need avatar in outside

Comment: Please check the update in the answer. As you have mentioned in question, the name is outside avatar. The link provided in the answer will also help you to figure out the solution for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it is because you are missing the `border-style` property. Try adding `border-style: solid;`.

You can also apply all three styles at the time by using `border: 1px solid #ff0000`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example:

```css
.avatar {
    border: 1px solid red;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
  <img class="avatar" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="" aria-hidden="true" data-noaft="">
```

Comment: it is work , but ı have .avatar >h3, how can ı use only for avatar

Comment: Can u share a Snippet using CodePen ?. Without knowing the HeaderOption Dom Structure can't give the exact solution.